# Why to use "May" before using "May God bless you"?

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs

I heard it many times but I haven't really pondered on that. We can hear these following sentences in our daily lives:

> 1. May God bless you.
> 2. May God be pleased with you.
> 3. May God accept your prayers.

But why do we use "May" at the beginning of the sentence? Apparently, it doesn't make the sentence a question but more polite and respectful towards the God maybe? I cannot tell I heard this structure in any other sentence but religious ones. Which grammar rule does it belong to? And how do we use it in different forms?

Comment: Should the word "be" be in the third example?

Comment: May the Force be with you.

Comment: *May I come in?*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[See meaning 4 of *may* at dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/may)

> (used to express wish or prayer): May you live to an old age.

It follows the same grammatical pattern as *let* (and is almost a synonym).

> Let their children grow up happy!
>
> May their children grow up happy!

The usage of *may* in this sense is not restricted to prayers, although one could say that it's formal, if not pompous, in modern usage.

Comment: To answer the second part of the question, we might add that the "May" is a modal verb in English, it is used in a subjunctive here to, as mentioned, express a wish or desire. It modifies the imperative, and turns it into an imperative of entreaty; or a 'jussive' (which is similar to the cohortative, "Let us...").

Answer (score 16):

Putting "May" first changes the sentence from a command to a request.  Rather than instructing God to bless someone, the speaker is rather hoping that God will do so.

Comment: Some people are offended when told "have a nice day!", thinking "don't tell me what kind of day to have!". For them, "May you have a nice day!" would be nicer. Similarly, using the bare imperative could be interpreted as telling God what to do, which is rude.

Comment: Exactly - I mentally (emotionally?) translate "may" to "I hope".

Answer (score 10):

When studying biblical hebrew, I ran into the usage of the jussive form - the third person form of the imperative. This is often used with relation to prayers. It is often translated as "may", so that may be the source of this usage - that is, a word that implies a command without actually commanding God.