# What does it mean "may you never take a single breath for granted"

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why to use “May” before using “May God bless you”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76706/why-to-use-may-before-using-may-god-bless-you)

I'm amused by the song "**I hope you dance**" from **Lee Ann Womack**, but I'm not sure if I understand the meaning of the following verse:

"I hope you never lose your sense of wonder
You get your fill to eat but always keep that hunger
***May you never take one single breath for granted***"

It would be much appreciated if anybody helps me to understand the meaning.

Comment: The *may you* construction is explained in [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76706/why-to-use-may-before-using-may-god-bless-you). [*Take for granted*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_for_granted) can be found in a dictionary, and so can the rest.

Comment: Hi  RegDwighт. and happy new year.